# Finding length of isosceles triangle

Tags: trigonometry, self-learning

I have the following homework question:
find the length of side `h`. Assume the largest triangle is isosceles.
[image]

The way I'm thinking about it is that the 2 same angles could be any of the following options:
[image]
[image]
[image]
The answer is assuming that the 2 angles in Option A are the same, `h=5.66`.
I don't understand why Option B and Option C cannot be viable options? Why can't the 2 angles in either Option B or Option C be the same?

Thank you

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsoscelesTriangle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the marked angle be $a$.

The other cases would imply $\frac{a}{2} + a + 90º = 180º$, or that $a = 60º$. This would mean that the triangle is equilateral. However, one of the sides is $2 + 2 = 4$, and one of the sides is $6$, so the triangle is not equilateral – a contradiction.

Therefore, the marked angles are the ones in the first case.